# Unable to upgrade Couchbase server Community Edition from 4.5 to 5

Tags: upgrade, couchbase

I tried upgrading my Couchbase server Community version form 4.5 to 6.0 via 5.0 v. as mentioned in
[Couchbase Official docuemntation](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/install/upgrade.html#supported-upgrade-paths-2).
Every time I run the 5.0 installer it gets rolled back due to the presence of 4.5v in the system.

Comment: Could you provide more details about which method you are using? It sounds like you are trying to install them on the same machine with a rolling online upgrade? Per https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/install/upgrade-online.html you need at least one extra node to do this.

Comment: I am trying using offline upgrade on the same machine.  Also, Will moving from 4 to 6 directly have the same result as moving from 4-> 5-> 6 v?

Comment: @MatthewGroves Could you please suggest

Comment: If you only have one machine in your cluster, you will need to uninstall the old version before you install the new version. You will need to make a backup of data, indexes, views, etc. Then, install the new version. Then, restore. Not the smoothest process, but that's one reason why multiple nodes are recommended in the first place.

Comment: It worked for me. Now I am easily able to upgrade from 5.x to 6.x as well using the same method. Thanks :)